# NavController CurrentDestination Seems Wrong

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm confused about how to manage the `currentDestination` from the Android navController, particularly in the context of using a `<dialog>`. Here is my scenario:

In my first fragment, I am navigating to a `DialogFragment` that presents a button. When that button is clicked, I update some live data that the first fragment is observing and call `dismiss()`. But when control returns to the first fragment, the `currentDestination` in the navController is still set to the dialog fragment!

Why isn't it set to the first fragment? I've also tried using a navigation to move from the dialog to the first fragment, but I get the exact same result.

Here is the code:

```
class AgendaFragment : Fragment() {
    private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by activityViewModels()
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentAgendaBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, 
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        binding = FragmentAgendaBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.someButton.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController.navigate(AgendaFragmentDirections.toDialog())
        }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        mainViewModel.someLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            Timber.d(findNavController().currentDestination)
        }
    }
}

class MyDialog : DialogFragment() {
    private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)

        binding = DialogMyBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        binding.button.setOnClickListener{
            dismiss()
            mainViewModel.someLiveData.postValue(true)
        }
}
```

**nav_graph.xml**

```
<fragment
    android:id"@+id/agendaFragment
    android:name="com.example.AgendaFragment">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/toDialog"
        app:destination="@id/MyDialog"
        app:popUpTo="@id/agendaFragment"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
</fragment>
```

Everything fires in the correct order. The log output looks like this:

> Destination(com.example:id/MyDialog)

But that fires from the AgendaFragment, so why is the current destination still set to the dialog and not to the AgendaFragment?

Comment: Are you sure about `popUpTo` and `popUpToInclusive` attributes in graph action? If you want to continue with doing some logic in `AgendaFragment`, they shouldn't probably be there.

Comment: @AndroidDev post your `MainViewModel` code also

Comment: Hi @AndroidDev, I am also facing the same issue. Have you found any solution? If yes, please share it. Thanks